# Разговор после переписки

Tags: диалог

Представьте себе следующую ситуацию. Вы переписываетесь с кем-то в чате, социальной сети или ещё где-то. Вы с ним на "вы", и он по положению выше Вас. Допустим, его зовут Иван Иваныч. В какой-то момент он пишет Вам: "Позвоните мне". Вы звоните сразу же, он "алё"... ***А что Вам лучше ответить?*** Сказать "Это я"? Будет ли это вежливым? Сказать "Здравствуйте, Иван Иваныч"? Но вы же только что переписывались, и странно опять здороваться. А сразу заговорить о деле без всяких "вводных" слов тоже как-то странно, да и, пожалуй, невежливо. ***Так какие же варианты или хоть один вариант начала такого разговора?***

В принципе, этот вопрос относится и к любым собеседникам, которые общаются на "ты", и он может быть ниже по положению, младше и т. д. Просто там отклонения какие-то от "нормы" будут восприниматься не так критично, поэтому я и акцентировал внимание именно на такой диспозиции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В какой-то момент он пишет Вам: "Позвони**те** мне". Вы звоните сразу же, он "алё"... ***А что Вам лучше ответить?***

Вне всякого сомнения, правила хорошего тона диктуют нам поздороваться и представиться.

> Сказать "Это я"? Будет ли это вежливым? Сказать "Здравствуйте, Иван Иваныч"? Но вы же только что переписывались, и странно опять здороваться.

Здороваться = желать здоровья.  **Ничего страшного** в том, что Вы пожелаете здоровья Ивану Иванычу "лишний" раз.  В силу того, что звонок и переписка в "чате" - не связанные друг с другом средства коммуникаций, логика подсказывает, что звонок мог быть от кого угодно другого.  На месте Ивана Иваныча я бы *не делал заключения*, что на другом конце провода - человек, с которым я только что общался по "чату".

"*Здравствуйте, Иван Иваныч.  Это - Артём Луговой, мы с Вами только что разговаривали в "чате"; Вы предложили позвонить.*"  А уж дальше дайте Иван Иванычу возможность объяснить предмет разговора или причину, по которой телефонный разговор предпочтительнее "чата"...

Помнится, что в правилах общения при личной встрече начинает разговор приветствием тот, кто моложе, а руку протягивает для пожатия тот, кто старше.

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор! Предпоследний абзац очень понравился, а в последнем у Вас так же, как и я всегда считал, как меня учили тоже.)) Единственное, разве кто-то воспринимает в наше время приветствие буквально, как пожелание здоровья? Что-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, Нет, конечно, не буквально.  Но при наличии сомнения буквальный смысл не вредно припоминать...

Comment: Кстати, а почему Вы "чат" в кавычках пишете?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, возможно потому, что я всё ещё сопротивляюсь повальному заимствованию...

Comment: Понятно. А у меня почему-то не было привыкания именно к этому слову. По всякому складывается. Сам даже не знаю, почему я его стал сразу спокойно использовать.

Answer (score 4):

По мне, наиболее удобной формой начала разговора будет форма "Иван Иванович, здравствуйте, вы просили вам позвонить". Если есть вероятность, что ваш номер не известен собеседнику, можно ещё и представиться (мало ли кто-то ещё параллельно решил позвонить). Обращение в начале предложения делает его менее официозным, а приветствие уместно, так как переписываться-то вы переписывались, а голос ещё не слышали. Если пожелание здоровья чем-то смущает, можно заменить на "рад вас слышать".

Comment: Спасибо, Марк!_